# Select option redirect get value and Display on redirect page

Tags: javascript, php

Question 1:

I'm doing a redirect on a select option in select box.  On the pages it's redirecting to (page 1 and page 2), is it possible to grab the value and display the select option value on the page it's redirecting to?

For example: 
Say I select page 1 on the select box.  On the page it's redirecting to (page1.php), is it possible to display that option value in the select box on that page (page1.php)?

Here's my code:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="page1.php>Page 1</option>
<option value="page2.php">Page 2</option>
```

Question 2:

Far as the select option redirect, is it possible to use PHP instead of the javascript onchange?  I found a php switch example but wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the value, I echoed selected="selected" on the page you redirect to. Here's the code -

Add this to the redirect pages:

```
<?php $requestType = $_GET['requestType'];?>
```

The redirect code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formType(value){
      if (value == 'ticket1') {
      window.location = "1.php?requestType=ticket1";
   } else {
      window.location = "2.php?requestType=ticket2";
       }
   }
</script>
```

The select

```
<select id="page" name="type" onchange="formType(this.value);">
<option value="">Select ....... </option>
<option value="ticket1" <?php if ($requestType == 'ticket1') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Ticket 1</option>
<option value="ticket2" <?php if ($requestType == 'ticket2') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Ticket 2</option>
</select>
```

This code provides an echo of selected="selected" on the redirect page which echos what was selected on the previous page.